# ¿Cómo escribir en un archivo de texto en JAVA?

Tags: java, archivo

¿Cómo puedo agregarle otro valor al archivo de texto sin que se borre el anterior, y después agregarle otro, y así sucesivamente (un valor cada vez que corra el programa) para finalmente obtener el total?

Código:

```
/*Programa que lea la descripción y la cantidad(precio), y guardarlo en un archivo, cada vez que se abra 
se debe ingresar un nuevo presupuesto sin perder los anteriores 

opciones que debe tener:
a)agregar un gasto
b)calcular el total gastado
c)borrar archivo y empezar uno nuevo*/

package javaapplication3;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class JavaApplication3 {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
     String ruta="c:/cosas/";
     String nombre="mis gastos.txt";
     //String desc;
     int n;
     File archivo=new File(ruta+nombre); 


        if (archivo.exists()) {
           FileReader fr =new FileReader(archivo);
           BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
           n= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            System.out.println("Tus gastos son los siguientes:");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                System.out.println(n);
                break;
                //desc= String.valueOf(i);
            }
        } else{
        n=0;
        FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(archivo);
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
        //System.out.println("¿Qué compraste?");
            //desc=sc.nextLine();
            //bw.write(""+desc);
            //bw.newLine();

        System.out.println("¿Cuánto gastaste?");
           n=sc.nextInt();
           bw.write(""+n);
           bw.flush();

        }




    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Esto sirve para versiones de java 7+.

Si sólo vas a hacerlo una vez, con la clase File lo puedes hacer de una manera sencilla:

```
try {
    Files.write(Paths.get(ruta+nombre), "Aquí el texto".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
}catch (IOException e) {
    //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
}
```

Sin embargo, si vas a estar escribiendo sobre el mismo archivo muchas veces, abriendo y cerrando el fichero en disco muchas veces, esto es una operación lenta. En este caso, un BufferedWriter es mejor opción:

```
try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("myfile.txt", true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw))
    {
        out.println("the text");
        //more code
        out.println("more text");
        //more code
} catch (IOException e) {
    //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
}
```

La respuesta original está más detallada (añade código por si la versión utilizada de java es menor a 7), puedes consutarla aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java

Comment: Hola Pablo, recuerda que puedes editar tu primer respuesta para no agregar mas, saludos¡

Comment: Se supone que mi primera respuesta está eliminada

Answer (score 2):

El siguiente ejemplo te crea el archivo si no existe, escribe en el sin borrar lo anterior.

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;

//SoftMolina

public class Escribir {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Un texto cualquiera guardado en una variable
        String saludo = "Hola";

        try {
            //Crear un objeto File se encarga de crear o abrir acceso a un archivo que se especifica en su constructor
            File archivo = new File("texto.txt");

            //Crear objeto FileWriter que sera el que nos ayude a escribir sobre archivo
            FileWriter escribir = new FileWriter(archivo, true);


            //Escribimos en el archivo con el metodo write 
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                escribir.write("SoftMolina");
                escribir.write("\r\n"); 

            }

            escribir.write(saludo);

            //Cerramos la conexion
            escribir.close();
        } //Si existe un problema al escribir cae aqui
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error al escribir");
        }
    }
}
```

Las clases **FileReader** y **FileWriter** permiten leer y escribir, respectivamente, en un fichero.

Lo primero que debemos hacer es importar estas clases y las que controlan las excepciones.

Después debemos crear un objeto de alguna de estas clases. Se pueden construir con un objeto **File**, **FileDescriptor** o un **String**. Nosotros usaremos este último.

Al crear un objeto de estas clases, deben estar dentro de un **try-catch**.

Recuerda que debemos controlar las excepciones.

Cuando creamos un objeto, abrimos un **stream** entre nuestro programa y el exterior, cuando debemos de usarlo debemos cerrar el **stream** con el método **close()**.